# Manually entering openid in iOS app fails

Tags: bug, login, openid, ios-app

I attempted to log in to the iOS app using a manually entered openid. After entering the URL, it just sat there with the little activity bar. I tried again using the fully qualified URL, including http:// and it did the same thing.

#### Update spring 2016

Same issue still exists.

Comment: I'll take a look at this.

Comment: could you tell me which openID provider you were trying to use?

Comment: Using 1.0.0 on iPhone iOS7.1.1. I'm unable too to log in using the stack exchange credentials. I'm using the same credentials as I used to log into the meta site. The app only says to retry later or contact meta.

Comment: Same thing happens here, but I'm hosting my own OpenID endpoint so entering manually is my only login option.

Comment: Any updates 2 years later? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Same behavior.  Sits there with the little blue activity bar wagging back and forth indefinitely.

Comment: OK, I've notified Brian in chat, hopefully he'll take a look. :)